# SDE of translated process $X(t) + a$

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

If I have a process $X(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ with the SDE $$dX(t) = F(X(t))dt + \sigma dW(t)$$

where $W(t)$ is Brownian motion, using Ito's rule, am I correct to say that the SDE from a linear transformation $$X'(t) = X(t) + a$$ where $a$ is constant would be
$$dX'(t) = dX(t) + a$$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, even though the notation $X'(t)$ is a bit confusing

Comment: Thank you @FeiCao, why is it not like $(F(X(t)) + a)dt$ is the $a$ from the $ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} (X(t) + a)$ ? part of Itos formula?

Comment: $dX'$ will be $F(X'(t)-a) dt + \sigma dW$ which is the same as $dX$ (but with the explicit dependence on $X$ being in terms of the original $X$ not $X'$). The point is that adding $a$ just shifts everything.

Comment: @user4933 If $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are two nicely behaved processes, in general you have $d(X(t) + Y(t)) = dX(t) + dY(t)$. Note that $da = 0$ if $a$ is constant.

Comment: @FeiCao, thank you so are we saying in our case $d( X(t) + a ) = dX(t) + da = dX(t)$ since $a$ is constant?

Comment: Yes. I have posted an formal answer to it

Comment: Thanks @FeiCao great answer there, I really appreciate the help !!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linearity, we have $$ dX'(t) = dX(t) + da = dX(t) = F(X(t))\,dt + \sigma\,dW_t = F(X'(t) - a)\,dt + \sigma\,dW_t.$$ Note that there is no need to for Ito's formula.